# Handling dropdown list in desktop app automation with Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, rpa

How to handle dropdown list while automation of desktop application by using Robot Framwoirk. ?

I am using select keyword and want to select the top value in dropdwon list rather to select a specific value like in below example i select 'WA'. How can i select dynamic value rather add static value.

*** Settings ***

Library        RPA.Windows

*** Keywords ***

Select           id:comboBoxPeopleAddressState    WA